# Бесконечная загрузка html файла

Tags: javascript, циклы

После этого кода страница стала бесконечно грузиться, не знаю в чем причина (код на JS)

```
for (let i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 12; ++j) {
        if (i = numbering[j]) {
            result += (array[i] + ' ');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что ваш цикл может быть бесконечным: `i = numbering[j]`

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка находится в условии:

```
      ↓
if (i = numbering[j])
```

Тут вы переменной `i` задаёте *новое значение* каждый цикл, из-за этого условие на остановку в `for(i)` не выполняется и зацикливается.